# Can't log in to Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have tried restarting my computer and a lot of other things. I can't log into the launcher the website, Technic, or Badlion. It just says: Could not connect to Mojang servers, or: Make sure you are logged in. It is allowed through the firewall. On the website it doesn't say anything, the log in button just turns black.

Comment: What specifically have you tried? It is either a problem with your internet or a problem with your account.

Comment: ...or a problem on Mojang's end, as this was 8 hours ago @Plasmic

Comment: True...but it was 16 hours ago, a point in time in which I successfully logged in so idk.

Answer (score -1):

You will probably have to re-install the program if it still does not work.